# Problema com Sockets PHP e html5

Tags: php, socket

Estou com um um problema, tenho uma página chamada servidor.php e outra cliente.php, o código da cliente é o seguinte:

```js
<script src="scripts/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
     
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:4000');

 socket.onopen = function () {
         
}
 socket.onmessage  = function(){
         alert("Chegou mensagem");
}
```

E o do servidor.php é

```html
<?php 
    
    ob_implicit_flush();
 set_time_limit(0);

    $host = "127.0.0.1";
 $porta = 4000;
 
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
 socket_bind($socket, $host, $porta);
 socket_listen($socket);

 echo "Esperando conexão com a porta: ".$porta;
 $con = false;

 switch(socket_select($r=array($socket),$w=array($socket),$e=array($socket),30)){
     case 0:
          echo "Tempo de espera terminou";
     break;
     case 1:
          echo "Conectado na porta: ".$porta;
    $con = socket_accept($socket);
     break;
     case 2:
          echo "Não foi possível se conectar!";
     break;
 }
 
    
 socket_recv($con,$resposta,1024,MSG_WAITALL);
  if(preg_match("/Sec-WebSocket-Key:(.*)\==/i", $resposta, $rep)){
          $key = $rep[1]."==";
  }
 $chave = base64_encode(sha1($key."258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"));

          $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n".
          "Upgrade: websocket\r\n".
          "Connection: Upgrade\r\n".
          "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n".
          "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$porta/\r\n".
          "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$chave\r\n\r\n";

    if(socket_write($socket, $upgrade, strlen($upgrade))){
     echo "Protocolo foi enviado";
    }else{
     echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
    } 

 
?>
```

O problema é que a função socket_write() não envia o socket para o cliente, não deveria aparecer a mensagem na página do cliente "Chegou mensagem"?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow, Edgar! Aproveite a sua visita e faça o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conhecer melhor como o site funciona! :)

Comment: Obrigado!, poderia me ajudar com esse problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois que você fez o handshake, você pode enviar as mensagens, precisa mascarar antes de enviar é receber.

```
//Desmascara a mensagem recebida
function unmask($text) {
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    }
    elseif($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    }
    else {
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }
    return $text;
}

//Mascara a mensagem para enviar para o cliente.
function mask($text)
{
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif($length >= 65536)
        $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
    return $header.$text;
}
```

Recebe o frame e desmascara a mensagem:

```
socket_recv($con,$resposta,1024,MSG_WAITALL);
$msg = unmask($resposta);
```

Enviar a mensagem:

```
$msg = "Teste";
$frame = mask(msg);
socket_write($socket, $frame, strlen($frame));
```

Eu te aconselho a usar uma biblioteca essa aqui por exemplo [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas eu deveria seguir exatamente essa instrução para mascarar uma mensagem? Digo, não posso personalizar ou é um padrão do socket mesmo?

Comment: Fica dando esse erro "failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out" no console do cliente

Comment: O WebSocket não e um "socket de navegador", Websocket é um protocolo, para se comunicar cliente/servidor você precisa seguir as especificações do protocolo.

Comment: O erro que deu foi porque a versão do protocolo do cliente é diferente do servidor.

Comment: E como eu posso resolver?

Comment: Usar uma biblioteca que já existe ou criar você mesmo.

Comment: Se você for criar aqui tem o link para a [especificação](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455) em inglês.

Comment: Ok obrigado, vou utilizar o Ratchet como você me aconselhou.

Comment: @Edgar Marca a resposta como a certa